# Android beacon library background snanning interval

Tags: android, altbeacon, beacon, eddystone

I use Android beacon library for scanning beacons.
I set this:

```
mBeaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(2000);
```

But scanning period is 10000ms for a while and sometimes 2000ms.

Is there any other code that I must implement?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the scan periods after you have already bound to the service, you must also call `updateScanPeriods()`.  Like this:

```
mBeaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(2000);
mBeaconMaanger.updateScanPeriods()
```